# Regexp exec not work in Edge

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a regexp, it works fine in Chrome/Firefox, but get null in Edge.

```js
var regexp = new RegExp("<header.*(?=)(.|\n)*?</header>", "g");
var str = "<body><header><h2>Title</h2></header><footer>footer</footer></body>";

var result = regexp.exec(str);
console.log(result[0]);
```

JSFiddle demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/JSDavi/k391qs72/2/

Please open it in different browsers. It's weird in Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works in all browsers.

```js
var regexp = new RegExp("<header[^\>]*\>((.|\n)*?)\</header\>", "g");
var str = "<body><header><h2>Title</h2></header><footer>footer</footer></body>";

var result = regexp.exec(str);
console.log(result[1]);
```